# Ideas how to call a REST API after a Jenkins Build with Data?

Tags: xml, rest, jenkins

We use SVN, Jenkins and Sonar doing CI and QA for XML development.

The xml-files are used in a software that allows to update/upload new xml-files via its own REST API.
There are PUT and POST methods available and of course the xml-file content has to be the POST/PUT Data in the body.

I would love to upload a new xml-file (to test instances of the software) after a successfull Jenkins build automatically using this REST API.
But I do not know how.

There is a Jenkins "HTTP Request" Plugin, that allows using GET and POST but I do not see a way of how to add Data from the workspace to it :(

Maybe you have some ideas? Or different approaches?

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `curl` directly, on a `Execute Shell` box. On that box, you have access to all variables Jenkins offers, and you can send your data.

Just be aware that if you try on your other side to get data from this particular job on Jenkins, it is not finished yet (its waiting the HTTP response), so you will need to schedule a call back. I faced this problem myself, to get build status from Jenkins API.

Here you get several examples of cURL usage: https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: Ok I think it is almost working. But with Jenkins I get a 302 Respone and the file is not updated, if I do the same PUT command with FireFox RESTClient I get a 200 and everything worked :/ This is my final curl command: 'curl --request PUT --data @/build_server/jenkins/jobs/xml_test/workspace/src/test.xml http s://xyz/api/1.0/123 --header Content-Type:application/xml'

Comment: If you are trying cURL commands, have you tried running them directly on the build machine? You execute all commands via Jenkins, and stop at the cURL line. Then ssh into the machine, and execute the final command to see exactly what is happening. This way you can debug it.

Comment: Great idea thank you. I think I found the problem: siteminder authentication needed. The 302 is a redirect to the *.fcc file. Will have to figure out how to authenticate via curl, does not seem to be so easy :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128906/curl-and-siteminder-authentication:   "You would need to post your credentials to the .fcc file, and manage the cookies that SM returns (look for SMSESSION cookie)" ... puh no idea how to do that :(

Comment: You can use -b and -c parameters to cURL, to get and send cookies. You can additionally set them directly, since they are just HTTP headers. Basically it says that you must use `-b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt`. Inside it you will have your cookies. You can then use this on the other cURL, so cookies will be on the go.

Comment: Great thank you, I got that with the cookies. But how can I "post the credentials to the fcc file" to get the cookie back? could not find any info via google (only this http://www.diaryfolio.com/curl-siteminder-automation-automating-authentication/) :/  Really appreciate your help :) As the original question was perfectly answered,  should I ask a seperate question for the siteminder stuff?

Comment: I believe yes. I am not aware of the fcc file you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows then you can also try using the Invoke-Webrequest cmdlet from PowerShell, which is very easy to use.

Comment: Good to know, great thank you. But I am on Linux (sry for forgetting to mention that), i will try below mentioned curl :) big THX